# Want to store NSRange and NSInteger inside NSMutableDictionry

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, nsinteger

I need to store both the `NSRange` object and `NSInteger` inside the `NSMutableDictionary`?

Can I do it?

If it is, Could you give me an example?

Comment: convert them to `NSValue` or `NSNumber`

Comment: Did you tried to do that ?

Comment: Take the risk to google before you ask! Similar questions in SO

Comment: The effortless don't deserve assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the `NSInteger` as `NSNumber` object.

```
mutableDictionary[integerKey] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:integer];
```

or even better

```
mutableDictionary[integerKey] = @(integer);
```

For `NSRange`, use `NSValue` object.

```
mutableDictionary[rangeKey] = [NSValue valueWithRange:range];
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used `NSString` for both `NSRange` and `NSInteger`, to remove confusion use this:

```
NSInteger i = 6;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange (25, 3);
    NSMutableDictionary *dic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic setObject:NSStringFromRange(range) forKey:@"range"];
    [dic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] forKey:@"integer"];
    //How to get it...
    NSRange range1 =  NSRangeFromString([dic objectForKey:@"range"]) ;
    NSInteger inte = [[dic objectForKey:@"integer"] integerValue];
```

Comment: Please explain before down vote. It will be batter to improve me

Comment: This is a sub-optimal solution because it involves string parsing each way.  There is already a class available to deal with what OP wants.